# How to store sentences in a temporary array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, temporary-files, temporary-objects

Currently, I am scraping out a chunk of data (paragraphs/strings) from a text file and writing it out to a new file. However, I am planning  on adding some conditionals later and thus want to be able to take out this chunk of data and only store it in a temporary array, then write out to a file if the conditionals are met. However, I am not sure how to write this out to an array without knowing the size of the array beforehand.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You can use ArrayList if you don't know about the size of the array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use an array. Use a collection of type String that can grow dynamically such as an [ArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for example. Here are some quick code samples: [Sample 1](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=234), [Sample 2](http://www.anyexample.com/programming/java/java_arraylist_example.xml)

Some notes on an ArrayList's memory management from the Java docs:

> The capacity is the size of the array
>   used to store the elements in the
>   list. It is always at least as large
>   as the list size. As elements are
>   added to an ArrayList, its capacity
>   grows automatically. The details of
>   the growth policy are not specified
>   beyond the fact that adding an element
>   has constant amortized time cost.
>
> An application can increase the
>   capacity of an ArrayList instance
>   before adding a large number of
>   elements using the ensureCapacity
>   operation. This may reduce the amount
>   of incremental reallocation.

Notice that even the docs do not specify exactly how things are managed internally.

Comment: I was thinking about an arraylist, but my question for either array or arrayList is, is there a limit on how large a string can be? Will a whole paragraph be read as a single string?

Comment: Limits on Strings and collections tend to be VERY large, think gigs and then don't think about the limitations. They are rarely a concern. As far as how a paragraph is interpreted, that is up to you and depends on the formatting of the data file.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I'll try using an ArrayList and see how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, an `ArrayList` (or any other type of Java collection) can take care of all the memory management for you:

```
ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
```

If you want to add a string:

```
strings.add("New String");
```

If you want to get a String at a certain index (in this example, index 1):

```
strings.get(1);
```

There are a lot more methods in the [ArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) class as well.

Answer (score 1):

You do need a collection that grows dynamically. `ArrayList` is the first that comes to mind; internally it is very similar to a regular array, so it offers fast random access, if you need it. `LinkedList` may be better suited if you don't have an estimate about the number of elements that you will eventually need, provided that you will only need sequential access to its elements (random access is available, but it will not be fast).